# Why is the pole vector constraint not in the same plane as the bone in Maya

Tags: maya, inverse-kinematics

If you create a pole vector constraint for ik in Maya, you can see that the locator and joint 1, joint 2, and joint 3 should be on the same plane.
[simple ik controller with pole vector constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scDJD.png)

This can also be verified by the following code

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import json, os, sys
import numpy as np

def gwp(obj_name):
    return cmds.xform(obj_name, q=True, ws=True, t=True)


def judgeSamePlane(p, plane_p):
    first = plane_p[0]
    second = plane_p[1]
    third = plane_p[2]
    normal_vector = np.cross(second-first, third-first)
    normal_vector = normal_vector/np.linalg.norm(normal_vector)
    target_vector = p - first
    target_vector = target_vector/np.linalg.norm(target_vector)
    print(np.dot(normal_vector, target_vector))

fp = []
fp.append(np.asarray(gwp("joint1")))
fp.append(np.asarray(gwp("joint2")))
fp.append(np.asarray(gwp("joint3")))
print("from_plane", fp)

tp = np.asarray(gwp("locator1"))
print("target_point", tp)

judgeSamePlane(tp, fp)
```

But in an ADV binding obtained from someone else, the locator and joint do not seem to be on the same plane

For example, for the hip-knee-ankle joint chain, when I only move the corresponding locator, they still satisfy a coplanar relationship. [only move locator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oncEn.png)

But if I move the ik controller at the ankle, then the locator and hip-knit-ankle will no longer be coplanar, which is not very consistent with my understanding of pole vector constraints. [move ankle ik controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnWv2.png)

Can anyone tell me where the error occurred or where my understanding was incorrect? Thank you very much!